# How to disable Toggle/Checkbox/Radio inputs in MMenu

Tags: javascript, mobile, mmenu

I have been using my own script and css for a switch that works over the input type 'checkbox' but once I added the mmenu library, my switches got messed up. Im using

```
<link type="text/css" href="static/css/jquery.mmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js"></script>
```

This should omit the toggles css and toggle js, but its still messing up my switch code.

Answer (score 0):

i was have some problem too.. i was remove the jquery >_< that is the fastest way...

1. try put jquery code on the top then place your code below the jquery code because computer read from top to bottom. ( if you are placing jquery on bottom jquery is replacing script on top )
2. if no 1 is not working too then ( that mean jquery is styling your checkbox ) write on your css input["checkbox"]{ ... }

Comment: Well non of this worked. The thing is Im using a special library for the checkboxes (http://ios-checkboxes.awardwinningfjords.com) it uses a CSS file plus some JS files. Is not that easy to arrange your 2nd suggestion option.

Comment: i write down before </body> closing tag `<!-- <script src="jquery-1.4.js"></script> -->
<script src="jquery/iphone-style-checkboxes.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(':checkbox').iphoneStyle({
  checkedLabel: 'YES',
  uncheckedLabel: 'NO'
});
    });
    
 
</script>
        
</body>`